# Moles Generation - Same Class name in Different Name space

Tags: moles, pex, pex-and-moles

This question was originally asked here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/pex/thread/60972f1f-735a-474e-be84-40cda8006ffa?prof=required.

I've recently installed Moles for VS2010. I have assembly that has same classes (same name) but under different namespace. Moles is resolving this by generating for example MClassName and MClassName01 for those classes. This works locally fine. But when someone else gets latest version, moles are regenerated and what has been  MClassName becomes MClassName01 and what has been MClassName01 becomes MClassName, due to which build fails until all unit tests are fixed again. Which is unacceptable to be done on each time when someone gets latest version. Please suggest solution.

The answer at the time was that it was a known bug that would be fixed in a release in December 2010.  I'm still seeing this issue in 0.94.51023.0.  Is this a regression or was the bug never fixed?

Thanks

Comment: You are definitely seeing a bug, try to contact MS research to report the bug. http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/bugs.aspx